# Grouping multiple columns under same header in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

These are my 3 current dataframes with same columns -

```
TP FP     TP FP     TP FP
 1  3      8 11      4  7
22 14     10 13      0 19
```

Here's how I want it in a single dataframe-

```
OCT-19    NOV-19    DEC-19
TP  FP    TP  FP    TP FP
 1   3     8  11     4  7
22  14    10  13     0 19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
headers = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["OCT-19"], ["TP", "FP"]])
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 3], [22, 14]], columns=headers)
```

Just use `MultiIndex.from_product()` to specify the headers you want for your columns. Then you can pass these headers into the columns of your dataframe.